# CMD show yes if a file was created/modified in the last 24 hours

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a script that will look in my backup folder and and show yes if there is a file in there from the last 24 hours and no if there isn't. all my backups are in zips (these are what I need to look at the date for) with the date of each backup in the file name. from what I have found I need to use SET variables and Loop command. I have been playing around with commands but don't have much yet.
The reason I need this in a script is because I have multiple backups I will be setting this for in one batch file.

Answer (score 0):

```
robocopy c:\backupFolder c:\backupFolder * /l /is /maxage:1 /njh /njs /ndl | find ":" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo no new file found
) else (
    echo new file found
)
```

Comment: Thanks, its working just as I need in testing, but how do I change the age to 12 hours? I tried changing 1 to 0.5 but then it told me there was a new file when there wasn't.

Comment: @user3726753, you can't do it using robocopy. It only has 1 day granularity on age selection. You can add to robocopy `/ts` to get the timestamp of each file in the 1 day range (ISO format, GMT zone, you have to deal with DST) and then determine if it falls in the needed time range.